# Is it possible to mount a volume to a custom drive prefix, e.g. "myDrive:\"?

Tags: windows, filesystems, drive-letter, logical-drive

Am I just a dreamer, or does something like this exist?

Comment: Mounting to a folder is going to be the closest thing.

Comment: One problem is that the `:` charachter is also used to separate the filename and the [Alternate Data Stream](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/windows-ntfs-alternate-data-streams) name. `MyDrive:Foo` names the Foo stream in the MyDrive file, not the Foo file in the Current Working Directory of the MyDrive disk. Also, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I figured that it may be easier with static shortcuts and such. For example, if I have a link to E:\etc, it is only useful if E: is still the same volume. I suppose a better solution would be to mount the volume to Z: or other never-used letters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you cannot. It is called a *drive **letter*** for a reason.

The command `myDrive:` gives the error

`'myDrive:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Note that is does not have to be a *letter* in the traditional sense. You can call your drive `[:`, for example.

DOS allowed you to use all ASCII characters between *A* and *`* (both inclusive), giving you a total of 32 different drive letters. I am not sure how to access the last 6 on Windows though.

The closest you can get to your "dream" is mounting. For example, you can mount a drive (a partition, actually) in the folder `C:\myDrive`.

Another "solution" that will work for the Windows Explorer is adding an expandable string value to the registry key

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`.

This is where the actual locations of *Desktop*, *My Music* and such are stored.

Comment: A drive letter does have to be A-Z, you cannot have a non alpha character. As you said "It is called a drive letter for a reason"

Comment: @DustinG.: I do not know about recent versions of Windows, but those that still had a config.sys can have drive letter that are not letters. All you need is 2 optical drives and specifying Z as the first drive letter for them. This is how I wound up with `[:` a couple of times...

Comment: @DustinG: Technically, DefineDosDevice() in Windows NT accepts *anything* in the 0x1..0xFF range. In practice, though, very few programs accept "`/:`" or "`[:`". (You can even define `foo:` that way, but it just won't work.)

Comment: @Dennis that seems to be a fluke with 3.1 or 9x, I would like to test that but there is no facility for directly or indirectly (as you propose) to give a drive a non alpha assignment on NT systems.

Comment: @DustinG.: I googled it and the 32 drive letters seem to be a special case of Windows 95, 98 and (possibly) Me. However, there is still a method that will work on Windows 7: Try `subst [: C:\ `. Now you have drive letter `[`.

Comment: @Dennis using the subst command, you are just creating a virtual drive "letter" so now the C drive takes both C: and [: and does help the OP with what they want.

Comment: @Dennis I do stand corrected on using a non alpha character to refer to a drive but it's limited and fairly useless

Comment: @DustinG.: Technically, it does have a use, which is now a new method to mess with coworkers. . .

Comment: @Dustin: It is, however, possible to create a subst-like mapping directly to the volume name (the `\\?\Volume{...}` path) without the need for an alphabetic drive letter assignment, by using the aforementioned DefineDosDevice() (which, by the way, is what subst itself uses).

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom named "drives" using the [PowerShell provider system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-7.2). You would do something like

```
PS> New-PSDrive -name myDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "F:"
```

You would then access the files/directories under that same drive like

```
PS> dir myDrive:\whatever\foo
```

It wasn't clear from your question if you were in a scripted/console environment or if you wanted to see this in Windows Explorer specifically. Also, I assume you were talking about a filesystem "volume". The PowerShell provider system also supports other kinds of providers.